# String.split("¤"); not working

Tags: javascript, string, split, currency, sign

So, I've got this task from school that drives me crazy. I am going to take data from a .dat file which contains this:

812¤SuperIT¤2015-12-06 18:00¤25

614¤MediaHuset¤2016-01-14 16:15¤67

My script works if I replace the "¤" with, for example, ";", but it doesn't work with "¤", "`&#164;`", "`&curren;`"

```
window.onload = start;

var xhttp;

function start() {
    document.getElementById('sub').onclick = load;
}

function load() {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = statusChange;
    xhttp.open('GET', '../presentasjoner.dat', true);   //GET or POST
    xhttp.send();

}
function statusChange() {
    if (xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200) {
        var content = xhttp.responseText;
        var lines = content.split("\n");

        document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            var parts = lines[i].split('&curren;');

            document.getElementById('table').innerHTML +=
            "<h4>" + parts[0] + "</h4>" +
            parts[1] + "<br/>" +
            "Antall plasser: " + parts[2] + "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Oppgave 1 - Oblig 5</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/common.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/common.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/oppg1.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="commonDiv">
            <a href="http://ask.hiof.no/~joakimsg/GRIT/WEB/html/fanpage.html"><h1>Oblig 4, Joakim Granaas</h1></a><br/>
            <h3>Oppgave 1</h3><br/>
            <input id ="sub" type ="submit" /><br/>
            <div   id="table"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try putting "&current"  instead of '&current' '' indicates char "" indicates string.

Comment: &current is a string not a char. (var lines = content.split("\n"); bet it works there)

Comment: @Puzzle84 Sorry deleted my comment before you replied haha. For the record I think it's "curren" not "current"

Comment: @Puzzle84, in js not matter what type qoutes: "sdf" and 'sdf' is same

Comment: @Puzzle84 Javascript doesn't differentiate between string and char.

Comment: Why don't you just use .split("¤") ?

Comment: @JoakimGranaas `&curren` is a HTML entity/HTML encoded form of the character `"¤"`. Is this script being interpreted by a _HTML parser_ before the _JavaScript interpreter_?

Comment: Thanks, I did'nt know that.  But it did'nt help in my case

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") ***must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error*** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: Usually `¤` just only indicates a non printable character and it __does not mean that this char is actually within your data__. Open the data file with an hex editor and have a look at the very separator ascii value

Comment: I have tried  "¤", "&#164" and "&curren"

Comment: In Chrome, when I do `"812¤SuperIT¤2015-12-06 18:00¤25".split("¤")` in the console the output is `["812", "SuperIT", "2015-12-06 18:00", "25"]`. Can you confirm that your string is actually showing that character when you try to split it?

Comment: All the data is probably HTML encoded. because it goes over through an xhttp request. try decoding your data after you split it on "\n"

Comment: I get a blacked out questionmark like this � between the values

Comment: Is ../presentasjoner.dat served with a [charset header](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting by "¤" def. works, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/s7t0c5jg/ --- so the issue is either elsewhere in your code OR your browser has a hard time processing the "¤" or you are saving your file as UTF8 or something and "¤" could be a higher character than just UTF8?

*After reading the comments above I think **Axel** is correct in saying **"Usually ¤ just only indicates a non printable character and it does not mean that this char is actually within your data. Open the data file with an hex editor and have a look at the very separator ascii value"***

JSFiddle source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">split by "¤"</button>
<p id="result"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Item1 ¤ Item2 ¤ Item3 ¤ Item4";
    var res = str.split("¤");
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is the character, but how do I change that? utf-16 didnt work

Comment: @JoakimGranaas What editor are you using? When you go to save the file make sure you select something higher than UTF8, or maybe even use encoding: none. - DreamWeaver (a joke, but commonly used)'s default encoding is UTF8 I think and it gives me issues with emoji characters because of that

Comment: I use Sublime Text 2. When I save, I don't get more options than File Name and File Type

Answer (score 0):

`¤` is probably just a nonprintable character. Use `od -c` to find out what it actually is, and split on that.

```
$ echo 'abc' | od -c
0000000   a   b   c  \n
0000004
```